# Determining number of left and right bracketing marks within region

Tags: region, delimiters

I want to write a function that uses a selected region and counts the number of left and right bracketing marks (whether `()`, `{}`, `[]`, `<>`).

I have started with this

```lisp
    (defun veak-count (region-start region-end)
      "todo
    Interactive functions enable them to be called using `M-x`"
      (interactive "r")  ; gets region start and end
    
      (message "Counting bracketing marks ...")
      (save-excursion
        (let (count)
          (setq count 0)
          (goto-char region-start)
    
          (while (and (< (point) region-end)
              (re-search-forward "\(" region-end t))
            (setq count (1+ count))) ))))


I then updated to use `count-matches`, but selecting the following line, gives 0 as count.

    (global-set-key (kbd "[")  'skeleton-pair-insert-maybe)

--------

 (defun veak-count (region-start region-end)
      "Count the `{` characters in the region.
REGION-START and REGION-END are the region limits."
      (interactive "r")
      (save-excursion
        (let ( (count (count-matches "\(" (point) region-end)) )
          (message "%d" count) )))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few fixes/optimizations to what you have (untested):

```lisp
    (defun veak-count (region-start region-end)
      "Count open-parens between REGION-START and REGION-END."
      (interactive "r")  ; gets region start and end
      (message "Counting bracketing marks ...")
      (save-excursion
        (let ((count 0))
          (goto-char region-start)
          (while (and (< (point) region-end)
                      (search-forward "(" region-end t))
                      ;; or for parens, brackets and braces:
                      ;; (re-search-forward "[([{]" region-end t))
            (cl-incf count))))))
```

Comment: I would like to have separate counts, count for number of `[`, count for number of `{`, count for number of `{`.  I think I should pass the opening parens, bracket and brace as a function parameter.  Still not sure if this would be good when using `(interactive "r")`.

Comment: That sounds to me like exactly the right approach.

Comment: How can I adapt it to count both the opening and closing parentheses?  The output would then be two numbers.

Comment: Can one colour the output when using `message` ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `M-x count-matches` to count matches for a regexp that specifies each char you want to count.

E.g `M-x count-matches (` counts the number of `(` chars in the region.

If you want to check for matching delimiter counts (e.g. `(` matching `)`) then just use `count-matches` in a function you define, that checks for both.

Comment: How can I make a regex string if I want to search for `(`.

Comment: `"("` is a regexp string that matches `(`. Because parens are common in Lisp, Emacs regexps require escaping them to use them as regexp grouping constructs `"\("`.

Comment: I do not think I require `(narrow-to-region start end)` in the code.  You think using it is better?

Comment: Right. I just edited the answer to remove that. `count-matches` already looks only in the active region.

Comment: Would the code be good for getting the count as I have done it ? Would I need more things?

Comment: Does it do what you want? If so, fine. (This isn't really a discussion site.)